# If $a+b, ab$ algebraic then $a,b$ are algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $L/K$ be a field extension and $a,b\in L $. It can easily be shown that if $a,b$ are algebraic over $K$ then sum and product are, too.

But I read that also the converse is true, say if $a+b$ and $ab$ are algebraic over $K$ then so is $a$ and $b$.

My strategy is to use that, since product and sum are algebraic we have that

$\displaystyle [\mathbb{Q}(ab,a+b):\mathbb{Q}]$ is finite, thus algebraic.

Now by using field operations (denoted $f$, e.g. multiplication, inverse ...) I somehow have to obtain an expression $a=f(a+b,a*b)$ and the same for $b$. Then the conclusion would follow. However, I could not achieve this.

Comment: Note that you don't need $a = f(a+b, ab)$, you only need $g(a) = f(a+b, ab)$ for some non-constant polynomial $g$.

Comment: If the sum and product are algebraic, then so is $(a+b)^2$, then so is $(a+b)^2-4ab=(a-b)^2$, then so is $a-b$, then so is ${a+b\over2}+{a-b\over2}$.

Comment: @Arthur Why would that be? If this is true, I would be done immediately, cause obtaining $a$ as a polynomial is not hard.

Comment: Because $f(a+b, ab)$ is algebraic, meaning $g(x) - f(a+b, ab)$ is a polynomial with algebraic coefficients, meaning its roots (one of which is $a$) are algebraic. So technically, you can even weaken it to there being a polynomial $h(x, y, z)$ such that $h(a, a+b, ab) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : $(X-a)(X-b) =X^2 - (a+b)X + ab$

Comment: Is this result true on field of charecteristics 2 also?

Comment: @SurajKulkarni : yes,I never divide by $2$ in this proof.